# Create a boundary box in android when using camera

Tags: java, android, image-processing, imageview, android-camera

I wanna create a fix size of box as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the openGL android sdk to draw simple shapes on the screen

Comment: I'm interested not only creating a box but also use that specific part of image in my app